# GCM connection error

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, smack

I am trying out implementing gcm server application using XMPP(CCS) and i cant able to connect to the google servers.
I am trying out the sample code from http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

when i try to connect

```
ccsClient.connect(userName, password);
```

i get the following error

```
gcm.googleapis.com:5235 Exception: XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.; : remote-server-error(502)
  -- caused by: XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.
  -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:592)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1010)
    at SmackCcsClient.connect(SmackCcsClient.java:249)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:342)
Nested Exception: 
XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.
  -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:565)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1010)
    at SmackCcsClient.connect(SmackCcsClient.java:249)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:342)
Nested Exception: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:557)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1010)
    at SmackCcsClient.connect(SmackCcsClient.java:249)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:342)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SmackCcsClient$GcmPacketExtension
    at SmackCcsClient.send(SmackCcsClient.java:130)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:357)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SmackCcsClient$GcmPacketExtension
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

I am using server key for the API key(password) 
and username="project number"+"@gcm.googleapis.com"

My project is whitelisted for upstream messaging
Ports considered to be closed are made open at my workplace. 5228, 5229, and 5230 for my IP.
which Ip should i use to open up the ports? public Ip or the other one?

What could be the problem?
Please help me resolve this! Thanks in advance

Comment: why you mention 5228, 5229, 5230, but trying to connect 5235?

Comment: @vitalyster- Note: If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM in order for your Android devices to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

Comment: Above note taken from http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you try from the command line - for example 
"telnet gcm.googleapis.com 5235"

If you see "Connected to gcm.l.google.com" - your firewall is good.

CCS ( the XMPP endpoint using by 3rd party servers ) is using port 5235 - 
the  5228, 5229 ports are needed for android/chrome devices connecting to GCM.

AFAIK 5230 is not one of our ports, not sure how you got it.